# Split polygon into four with respect to single point

Tags: polygon, point, open-source-gis, intersection

Some days ago one of my colleague came to ask me a query related to Geometries.

The situation is as....
 There is one Polygon (suppose a city polygon) and there is one point (suppose user's current location) inside that polygon.

Now, what I have to achieve is to split polygon into four quadrant so as the lines which splits polygon into four should be perpendicular to each other and should pass from point. (please see image to help with understanding).

In other words, this processing will generate four section of polygon as NE,SE,SW and NW with respect to point(user's location).[image: Here is how this will do.]

So, how to achieve it? One immediate thought in my mind was to 
**1]Compute the bounds of polygon
 
2]Get distance by max-min/2

3]Use this as a radius of buffer which will drawn from point.

4]Then get the intersection of this buffer and original polygon

5]From these intersection to point draw a lines to split the polygon.**

Unfortunately, it's need not be always right (simply bcoz point could be anywhere inside polygon).

It would be great if anyone find a way to solve this problem.

I'm trying to solve this problem using opensource Geospatial libraries and software's.

Comment: I think you got lost at step 2.  Wouldn't it be enough to construct four rectangles with "point A" as the LR, UR, LL, and LR corner and using the MBR corners for the other diagonals?  From there you just need to clip the original shape with the four extents to produce quadrants. It might be wise to floor the minimums and ceil the maximums of the MBR, but the math should work either way.